# IBM SBT :Using Forum API to create discussion forum

Tags: sbt, connection

How to add the discussion forum in existing application?

Configured with the my application running in WAS and using java snippets i can able to get connected to the connections and get the response .

But with javascript snippets there is a problem .Unable to configure SBT JS and run javascript snippets.

https://localhost:9443/sbt/WebContent/js/sdk/sbt/connections/ForumService is not found

always 404 error in web console.

please help me out

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make sure you have the sbt.web project on your server. It sounds like the ForumsService dojo file isn't found.

Also make sure that your managed-beans.xml file is configured, and set properly to point to your connections server.

Here is a snippet which shows the path invocation for ForumService.  You can see many more examples in the GitHub Project and reference the wiki which describes your first JS App http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=SDK+docs#action=openDocument&res_title=Adding_the_SDK_to_your_web_application_SDK1.0&content=sdkcontent

```
require(["sbt/connections/ForumService", "sbt/dom", "sbt/json"], 
    function(ForumService, dom, json) {
        var forumService = new ForumService();  
        var forumUuid = "%{name=ForumService.forumUuid}";   
        var promise = forumService.getForum(forumUuid);
        promise.then(
            function(forum) {
               dom.setText("json", json.jsonBeanStringify(forum));
            },
            function(error) {
                dom.setText("json", json.jsonBeanStringify(error));
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks Paul for the reply